# JPA @OneToMany and @ManyToOne: back reference is null though mappedBy is included

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 4 Entities, that a related to each other with `@OneToMany` relationships.
When I try to save `Order` that contains `OrderItem` - `Orderitem` has no backreference.

In the code below only important fields are showed for brevity ( usual strings and primitives are omitted ). I decided to include `Dish` and `User` Entities also.

**Order:**

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "order",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        orphanRemoval = true)
    private List < OrderItem > orderItems;
}
```

**Dish:**

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Dish {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "dish")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List < OrderItem > orderItems;
}
```

**OrderItem:**

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class OrderItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Dish dish;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Order order;
    private int quantity;
}
```

**User:**

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "user",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List < Order > orders;
}
```

The problem happens when I try to save `Order` with Spring data JPA.
Let's print Order to see `OrderItem` **before saving**.

```
public Order saveOrder(Order order) {
    System.out.println("SERVICE saving order " + order);
    return orderRepository.save(order);
}
```

As you can see, orderItems backreference is null before saving ( I though spring data jpa should deal with setting it ).

> SERVICE saving order Order(id=0,
> orderItems=[OrderItem(id=0, quantity=2, order=null)])

Here is what I have in DB ( Order and OrderItem entities ).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your `OrderItem` class, add annotation below:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable = false)
Order order.
```

One more thing, I suggest you use SEQUENCE_GENERATOR, beacause IDENTITY means: I'll create the entity with a null ID and the database will generate one for me. I don't think Postgres even supports that, and even if it does, a sequence generator is a better, more efficient choice.

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer,
I've added these and it still tries to persist null that leads to this exception.
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "order_id" violates not-null constraint`
 `Detail: Failing row contains (1, 1, 1, null)`

Maybe my understanding of JPA is wrong and I have to manually set relation on `OrderItem` side before persisting? But I do not do this for `User` entity when I save `Order` and it works as expected and has a back reference.

Comment: I updated my answer. I didn't notice that you are using IDENTITY as GenerationType.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my code with Generation_Sequence, unfortunatelly that doesn't help with the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

The best option that I found for this is doing something like:

```
order.getOrderItems().forEach(orderItem -> orderItem.setOrder(order));
```

Before your `save()` call. Even though `order` is not persisted at this point, it seems like Hibernate can resolve the relation and the back references will be set correctly.

If you do not want to bother setting the back reference in your business logic, you can add something like this to your entity:

```
class Order {
    ...
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        setMissingBackReferences();
    }

    private void setMissingBackReferences() {
        orderItems.forEach(oderItem -> {
            if (oderItem.getOrder() == null) {
                oderItem.setOrder(this);
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```